# Nativescript socket reconnection

Tags: sockets, socket.io, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a problem reconnecting the client sockets after restarting my server (NodeJs).

In the client I'm using [nativescript-socket.io](https://github.com/naderio/nativescript-socket.io).

```
   this.socketIO = SocketIO.connect(SocketBaseURL + '/travel_' + this.travel._id, options);

   this.socketIO.on('connect', (socket) => {
                    console.log('Socket connected!);
                });

   this.socketIO.on('connect_error', (socket) => {
                    console.log('Socket error!');
                });

   this.socketIO.on('reconnect', (socket) => {
                    console.log('Socket reconnected!')
                });

   this.socketIO.on('event', () => {
                    console.log("new event!!!!")

                });
```

The thing is **It reconnects!** console prints "socket reconnected!". But after that reconnection the client does not receive any more "event".

Does anyone know the right way to handle reconnection using this library?

**EDIT** 
I already tried this [solution](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2476)

Answer (score 0):

I used https://sailsjs.com as a nodejs backend because socket.io is already integrated on it.

by calling `sails.io` you can already use socket events. see this link for examples: https://gist.github.com/mikermcneil/6598661 and I don't have a problem about reconnecting like yours.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Janno. I'll look into it but right now I need to resolve this with NodeJs

Comment: did you checked this issue? it might help you https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2476

Comment: Yeah mate, just tried that approach without success.